Whenever I use deposit method and then check balance method the balance doesnt update any fixes please?
balance = 0
def display_menu():
    balance = 0
    choice = ' '
    if choice == ' ':
        print('1.Check Balance \n2.Deposit \n3.Withdraw \n4.Exit')
        choice = int(input('Please make a choice: '))
        if choice == 1:
            check_balance()
            display_menu()
        elif choice == 2:
            balance = deposit(balance)
            display_menu()
        elif choice == 3:
            balance = withdraw(balance)
            display_menu()
        elif choice == 4:
            print('Thank you have a good day')
        
def deposit(balance):
    deposit_amount = float(input('Please enter the amount you wish to deposit'))
    balance += deposit_amount
    print(f'The updated balance is: {balance:.2f}')
    return balance 
      
def check_balance():
    print(f'Balance is: {balance:.2f}')
       
display_menu()


why are you doing balance = 0 in display_menu ?

Also why are you recursively calling display_menu() ?

There are three main problems with your code:

You are reinitializing the balance to 0 in the display_menu every time it is called. One way to fix this is by replacing it with global balance. But an even better approach is to give it the balance parameter.

The check_balance function does not use the updated balance. Use the same approach with that.

The withdraw function is not defined. I assume you have (or will) define it though.


So, one way to fix this would be like this:
# removed the global `balance` and added `balance` parameter
def display_menu(balance=0):
    choice = ' '
    if choice == ' ':
        print('1.Check Balance \n2.Deposit \n3.Withdraw \n4.Exit')
        choice = int(input('Please make a choice: '))
        if choice == 1:
            check_balance(balance)
            display_menu(balance)
        elif choice == 2:
            balance = deposit(balance)  # added `balance` parameter
            display_menu(balance)
        elif choice == 3:
            balance = withdraw(balance)
            display_menu(balance)
        elif choice == 4:
            print('Thank you have a good day')


def deposit(balance):
    deposit_amount = float(input('Please enter the amount you wish to deposit'))
    balance += deposit_amount
    print(f'The updated balance is: {balance:.2f}')
    return balance


# added `balance` parameter
def check_balance(balance):
    print(f'Balance is: {balance:.2f}')


# added withdraw function
def withdraw(balance):
    withdraw_amount = float(input('Please enter the amount you wish to withdraw'))
    if withdraw_amount > balance:
        print('Insufficient funds')
    else:
        balance -= withdraw_amount
        print(f'The updated balance is: {balance:.2f}')
    return balance


display_menu()

